# GitHub Desktop only detects changes when the code is saved

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-desktop

GitHub Desktop doesn't detect any code changes in real-time. It only displays "No local changes".

[image]

It only displays changes once I've saved the file in Visual Studio Code.

before saving

[image: before saving]
after saving
[image: after saving]
GitHub Desktop after saving the file in VSCode
[image: img]

How do I make it detect changes in real time?

Comment: do you  expect that GitHub Desktop has access to the memory use of VSC? Save frequently or automatically, why don't use the SCM gutter of VSC

Comment: You could enable auto save on focus change in the settings of VS Code.

Comment: what is the purpose of showing your desktop wallpaper, you can capture with Print Screen the current window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what ElpieKay said, I enabled autosave on focus change in the settings of VS Code. Now GitHub will detect changes in real-time.